# Init a FloatingPoint from a string

Tags: swift, generics, floating-point, protocols

I am trying to convert a 2d array of `String`s into my custom generic type `Matrix`:

```
func convert(_ arr: [[String]]) -> Matrix<Element> {
    var m: Matrix<Element> = Matrix()
    for row in arr {
        var v: [Element] = []
        for e in row {
            let convE: Element = Element(string: e) // right here I'd like to implement something like that: Element(string: e)
            v.append(convE)
        }
        m.vectors.append(Vector(v))
    }
    return m
}
```

The `Matrix.Element` does conform to the `FloatingPoint` protocol. Please tell me if you wish to see the `Matrix` struct but I think I haven't implemented anything that's important for this question other than that the generic `Element` type of `Matrix` does conform to the `FloatingPoint` protocol.

My problem is I want `Element` to be something like `Float`, `Double`... (any of the `FloatingPoint` types) but how can I initialize a FloatingPoint from a string? I tried:

```
extension FloatingPoint {
    init(string: String) {
        self.init(Int(string)!)
    }
}
```

which obviously only works for strings like "1", "2"... and not "1.2", "3.541" and so on which I want.

**Edit:**(@Leo Dabus)

```
protocol DArray: Sequence {
    associatedtype Component: FloatingPoint
}
extension  DArray {
    static func * <T: DArray>(lhs: Self, rhs: T) -> Vector<Component> {
        let v = lhs as? Vector<Component> ?? rhs as! Vector<Component>
        let m = lhs as? Matrix<Component> ?? rhs as! Matrix<Component>
        return Vector(m.map { zip(v, $0).map(*).reduce(0, +) })
    }

    static func / <T: DArray>(lhs: Self, rhs: T) -> Vector<Component> {
        let v = lhs as? Vector<Component> ?? lhs as! Vector<Component>
        let m = lhs as? Matrix<Component> ?? lhs as! Matrix<Component>
        return Vector(m.map { zip(v, $0).map(/).reduce(0, +) })
    }
}

struct Vector<Component: FloatingPoint>: DArray {
    var components: [Component]
    var count: Int {
        return components.count
    }

    init(_ Components: [Component] = []) {
        self.components = Components
    }

    subscript(i: Int) -> Component {
        get {
            return components[i]
        } set {
            components[i] = newValue
        }
    }

    static func + (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self {
        return Vector(zip(lhs, rhs).map(+))
    }

    static func - (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self {
        return Vector(zip(lhs, rhs).map(-))
    }

    static func * (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self {
        return Vector(zip(lhs, rhs).map(*))
    }

    static func / (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self {
        return Vector(zip(lhs, rhs).map(/))
    }

    func empty(of length: Int) -> Self {
        return Vector(Array(repeating: 0, count: length))
    }
}

struct Matrix<Component: FloatingPoint>: DArray {
    var vectors: [Vector<Component>]
    var nRows: Int {
        return vectors.count
    }
    var nColumns: Int {
        guard !vectors.isEmpty else { return 0 }
        return vectors[0].count
    }
    var count: Int {
        return vectors.count
    }

    init(_ vectors: [Vector<Component>] = []) {
        self.vectors = vectors
    }

    subscript(r: Int) -> Vector<Component> {
        get {
        return vectors[r]
        }
        set {
            vectors[r] = newValue
        }
    }

    subscript(r: Int, c: Int) -> Component {
        get {
            return vectors[r][c]
        }
        set {
            vectors[r][c] = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

Additionally I have my two `struct`s conform to the Sequence protocol.

Comment: The problem here is that there is no generic initializers that takes a String. Double, Float, CGFloat, they all implement their own string (StringProtocol) fallible initializers. Btw FloatingPoint it is not a type it is a protocol.

Comment: You can not initialize an array of FloatingPoint elements.

Comment: should I use another protocol as generic constraint?

Answer (score 0):

(Note: I am the OP)

What I came up with now is:

```
extension FloatingPoint {
    public init?(string: String) {
        if Self.self == Double.self {
            self = Double(string) as! Self
        } else if Self.self == Float.self {
            self = Float(string) as! Self
        } else if Self.self == Float80.self {
            self = Float80(string) as! Self
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

It works for my use case but I was wondering whether it is a good way of achieving what I am looking for. So I'd be happy for someone to evaluate my solution. (@Leo Dabus)

Comment: This will crash if you pass an invalid string. I think you should edit your question and post you struct and how you are going to use this. You shouldn't need to extend FloatingPoint protocol to add an initializer that it is already present on the types itself. Btw what type you expect as a result when using it?

Comment: I edited the question. I expect to get the type Self as result

Comment: and for how I want to use it: I have a array like `[[String]]` and want to convert it to a Matrix

Comment: @LeoDabus You said: You shouldn't need to extend FloatingPoint protocol to add an initializer that it is already present on the types itself. That's what I thought... btw I edited my question

Comment: @LeoDabus I have encountered the same problem with `pow`. Pow can be used on all the FloatingPoint types but I just figured out how to do it like in my answer above

Comment: I have posted a generic method to convert StringProtocol types to FloatingPoint types

Answer (score 0):

You can extend `FloatingPoint` protocol and constrain the generic type to `LosslessStringConvertible`:

```
extension StringProtocol {
    func floatingPoint<T: FloatingPoint>() -> T? where T: LosslessStringConvertible {
        T(String(self))
    }
}
```

---

Note that `CGFloat` does NOT conform to `LosslessStringConvertible` so you would need to implement a custom `String` initializer:

```
extension CGFloat: LosslessStringConvertible {
    private static let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    public init?(_ description: String) {
        guard let number = CGFloat.formatter.number(from: description) as? CGFloat else { return nil }
        self = number
    }
}
```

---

```
let double: Double? = "2.7".floatingPoint()       // 2.7
let float: Float? = "2.7".floatingPoint()         // 2.7
let float80: Float80? = "2.7".floatingPoint()     // 2.7
let cgfloat: CGFloat? = "2.7".floatingPoint()     // 2.7
```

---

There is already an initializer for `FloatingPoint` types but to make your code work you need to conform your Matrix Component to `LosslessStringConvertible`.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try something like this:

```swift
extension FloatingPoint where Self == Double {
    init(string: String) {
        self.init(Double(string)!)
    }
}

extension FloatingPoint where Self == Float {
    init(string: String) {
        self.init(Float(string)!)
    }
}
```

this should work as well

```swift
extension FloatingPoint {
    init(string: String) {
        self.init(Self(string)!)
    }
}
```

Comment: No you can't because FloatingPoint has no initializer that takes a float or double... so you get the error message  Initializer 'init(_:)' requires that 'Double' conform to 'BinaryInteger'